# “He must do military service” or “He has to do…”

Tags: word-choice, semi-modals

I wanted to make sure I understand Michael Swan's explanation from Practical English Usage correctly. It's not wrong to use "have to"  to talk about obligations that come from the speaker, is it? As in "I have to call my aunt". According to Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*,

> Have to can also be used to talk about obligation coming from the speaker or hearer, in the same way as must. This is normal in AmE which uses must less often in this sense) and is becoming very common in British English.
>
> 1. "I really have to stop smoking." (Or *I really must*…)
> 2. "Do I have to clean all the rooms?" ( Or *Must I…*?)"

The second example is about externally imposed obligations and the book says  both "must" and "have to" are correct.

Does this mean that in this example from another book: "He **has to** do military service next year" I can use "He **must** do military service"?

Comment: Sorry, can you clean up and clarify the question a bit? 1) Where does the quote from Swan end? Does it include the numbered examples? 2) I'm not clear exactly what the question is, or why we're distinguishing between self-imposed and external obligations. If the answer is "can I use either," the answer is "There is significant difference (still) between AmE and BrE usage."

Comment: @Andy Bonner, sorry. This is from Swan: Michael Swan's Practical English Usage "Have to can also be used to talk about obligation coming from the speaker or hearer, in the same way as must. This is normal in AmE which uses must less often in this sense) and is becoming very common in British English.

"I really have to stop smoking." Or I really must...)
"Do I have to clean all the rooms?" ( Or must I?)"

Comment: @Andy Bonner my question is when talking about externally imposed obligations, can "must" be used  instead of "have to"? I am not sure I understand the book's example but I think it shows in its second example that *must* can be used when talking about externally imposed obligations. If it's true then can I use *must* in this example too: "He must do military service next year"

Comment: @Andy Bonner this is the book's second  example about as I think externally imposed obligations: "Do I have to clean all the rooms?" ( Or must I?)"

Comment: It depends heavily on how often you use a passive present tone.  Passive present tone is permitted in English; but, many people feel that avoiding it makes one's writing more engaging.  "Must" implies are requirement in fewer words, while "has to do" implies a present state of something that will be performed.  As you can see,, even the explanation is cleaner when using verbs that express the idea more directly (instead of verb phrases that do so with many words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a British English speaker, I don't find *He must do military service next year* natural. I would use *have to* for external obligations and *must* for personal resolutions or giving advice etc. to another person.

> I must remember to buy some butter when I go to the supermarket.
>
> You must take your umbrella when you go out.
>
> You must come and see me next time you're in town.

Comment: does Swan's example below (in this comment) refer to external obligations? And does it suggest that with external obligations it's possible to use must?
"Do I have to clean all the rooms?" ( Or must I?)"

Comment: If cleaning rooms is part of the duties of a new job, I would find _have to_ more natural. "_Must_ I clean my room now?" sounds more like a child moaning about something their mother has asked them to do!

Comment: So I don't misunderstand and the book does say that *must* can be used to talk about externally imposed obligations in BrE  under the influence of American English. Right?

Comment: I didn't mean to say that _must_ **couldn't** be used, just that I found it less idiomatic in that particular context (unlike some American contributors).

Comment: I disagree: He must do etc. can be externally imposed. Must is just stronger than has to.

Comment: @Kate Bunting so I can use "must" to refer to externally imposed obligations but in some contexts in may not be idiomatic in BrE but it could be idiomatic in AmE. In this example He must do military service. Right?

Comment: @Lambie do you find it not idiomatic in "He must do military service?"

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, "have to" is perfectly fine in these cases, and it is actually much more common in casual conversation than "must" in AmE.
2. Both of your examples are correct with "must" or "have to," but again "have to" would be more common in these cases.
3. Yes, "he must do military service next year." Is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for the source of the obligation—self-imposed or external—to influence the choice between "must" and "have to." The main consideration, as Swan mentions, is British vs American usage. You *can* use "must"; you can even use it in American contexts, though it might influence your tone in ways you don't intend. And apparently "have to" is increasing in British usage.

There's also [the usage that adds "got" to "have"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-and-have): "I've got to stop smoking." This is generally seen as more informal, and you'll still find some sources urging you to delete "got" and only use "have," but it's widespread in conversational usage (again, mostly in American English).

Comment: I think he does make this distinction. "To talk about an obligation that comes from "outside" (for instance a regulation , or an order from somebody else) we usually prefer "have to'".

Answer (score 1):

In American English, “have to” is much less formal.  It is impossible for me to imagine anyone under 21 saying to a peer, “I must go home”, and even among adults, it would be a strangely formal register for casual speech.  For an even more casual version, try “got to”.

Paradoxically, “must” is often used in a near-slang sense to mean “circumstances make it certain that” (rather than “circumstances make it *obligatory* that”):

- “You must be Joe’s brother.”
- “This must be the worst movie I have ever sat through.”

I got to go.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable. But they have different meanings.

He has to do military service next year. - external obligations

He must do military service.- I want/ the speaker wants...

have to - external obligations

must- personal choice/advice

You must stay tonight- I want you to stay tonight.

You have to stay tonight.- You are compelled to stay tonight.