# What is the difference between "must" and "have to"?

Tags: word-usage

Is there a difference between a sentence like "This must stop." and "This has to stop."

Comment: Discussed at length [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310221/he-must-or-he-has-to/310332#310332).

Comment: No: stative "have" expresses obligation or necessity, much the same as "must" does. In general, there are no semantic differences. Note that it is replaceable by the idiom "have got"

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between the two sentences.

This must stop. (The speaker wants this to stop.)

This has to stop. (External obligations)

Comment: What is your source for this?  It does not sound like any rule I know.  For example, there is the proverb ["All good things must come to an end"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-good-things-must-come-to-an-end), which certainly doesn't mean "The speaker wants all good things to stop."

Comment: Both are used for obligation. 'Have/has to' - impersonal, must- personal

Comment: Stative "have" expresses obligation or necessity, much the same as "must" does. In general, there are no semantic differences. Note that it is replaceable by the idiom "have got".